# EF Code First Not creating database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have copied my code across into a new project and I am failing to see any .mdf or .log files generated after running. Under Data Connections I can see and interact with the tables in the database, yet no files are created within the App_Data folder.

Here is my DB context class:

```
public class BareCupboardDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NutritionalValue> NutritionalValues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RecipeStep> RecipeSteps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
}
```

My Application_Start() code:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        //System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new BareCupboard.Models.RecipeContextInitializer());
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BareCupboardDB>());

        var context = new BareCupboardDB();
        context.Database.Initialize(true);
    }
```

And my connection string:

```
<add name ="testConnection"
     connectionString="data source= .\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=BareCupboardDB"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

As far as I can see, this should absolutely generate my database files.

I appreciate any help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string is to an SQL Server instance so you should find the tables in there.  You can use SQL Management Studio to have a look

Comment: Are you talking about the tables that are visible under Data Connections? as I am able to view "testConnection" and its associated table data.